# Н и нн в кратком причастии осознан

Tags: причастие

Одно предложение начинается примерно так:

> Это чувство неосознано (или
> осознано в малой степени).

Здесь краткое прилагательное, но уж очень хочется его написать с двумя н и превратить его в причастие.

В первом примере употребления мы должны написать слово с двумя н, поскольку есть приставка `не`. Во втором случае краткое страдательное причастие пишется с одной `н`. Получается какая-то непоследовательность. С другой стороны, можно бы написать его таким образом:

> Это чувство не осознано (или осознано
> в малой степени).

Какой из вариантов верен?

Answer (score 1):

ПРАВИЛО

Тематика вопроса - различение причастий и отпричастных прилагательных в краткой форме, например: выводы обоснованы научными фактами – выводы точны и обоснованны; дети избалованы родителями – они капризны и избалованны.

Некоторые причастия образуют пары "причастие - отпричастное прилагательное". Причастие переходит в прилагательное при наличии следующих признаков: 1) обозначает качественный признак, отвечает на вопрос каков; 2) имеет переносное, а не прямое  значение; 3) можно заменить синонимичным прилагательным; 4) возможны однородные отношения с другими прилагательными.

РЕШЕНИЕ

(1) Неосознанное чувство - еще не осознанное мною чувство, чувство не осознано (это причастие, сохраняется значение действия, ясен производитель действия).

(2) Неосознанное, интуитивное чувство - чувство неосознанно, интуитивно (это отпричастное прилагательное, нет значения действия, однородные отношения с качественным прилагательным).

ПРИМЕРЫ

(1) Россия подняла и гордо несет знамя новой науки ― геохимии, значение которой еще не осознано. Но действие назовут несознательным, если не осознано было существенное последствие или результат этого действия,

(2) Так что если человек не осознает мотива, не является аргументом того, что мотива нет. У детей и животных они неосознанны. У многих взрослых тоже.

Эти программы неосознанны, функционируют в автоматическом режиме и порой противоречивы, но именно они определяют едва ли не все наши высокие порывы и тонкие душевные движения.

(3) Как собственно область прекрасного, искусство в средние века ещё не осознано (написание спорно, здесь, скорее, значение "неосознанно, интуитивно").